# An issue with instantiating a prefab. ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-machine

I am trying to instantiate my enemy prefab called Ghoul. In this, I have something called GhoulDeath which is just an overridden version of vp_DamageHandler. But after there is a couple of ghouls in my scene it breaks.

```
public class ghoulDeath : vp_DamageHandler
{
    public Animator animGoul;
    public int kills;
    public bool death;

    public override void Damage(vp_DamageInfo damageInfo)
    {
        if (CurrentHealth > 0)
        {


            base.Damage(damageInfo);
            animGoul.Play("getHit1", 0, 0.25f);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well what is a `vp_DamageHandler`? And can you post the complete Exception you get?

Comment: This error is most likely a result of trying to add a key to a dictionary which already contains that key. You are not providing enough information for us to identify exactly what's wrong, though. Try posting the entire stack trace (select the error in the editor and CTRL+C).